# powershell highlight the blank space found

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, highlight

I have the following script which finds a blank space in a csv file by going line by line

```
$yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes", "Retain blank space."

$no = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No", "Delete blank space."

$n = @()

$f = Get-Content C:\MyPath\*.csv 
foreach($item in $f) {

if($item -like "* *"){ 
    $res = $host.ui.PromptForChoice("Title", "want to keep the blank on this line? `n $item", [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes, $no), 0)

    switch ($res) 
    {
        0 {$n+=$item}
        1 {$n+=$item -replace ' '}
    }


} else {
    $n+=$item -replace ' '
}

}

$n | Set-Content  C:\MyPath\*.csv
```

The question is: When there is a space found, how can I highlight where it is on a line or put a color there, anything that would ease the process of finding it?

**EDIT:** don't want to alter the file or the text, this should be done only shown in the console for PowerShell or in the window popup for ISE.

Comment: That would be a function of the editor that you are using to view the file. Not Powershell.

Comment: replace the space with a special char such as `§` it will be easy to find it then

Comment: i am getting the string in the console. Not in some editor @EBGreen

Comment: @Kayasax I don't want to alter the file in any way. If i launch the script from PowerShell, then i see the text in console. If I launch it from ISE then I see it as a popup on screen. I want in that popup or in the console to somehow make the space more visible. Ideas? If I didn't have to prompt the user for a response, probably I could have just used `ctrl + left arrow` to jump to the blank

Comment: In that case you could use Kayasax's suggestion to replace the space, or you could look at using Write-Host and changing the background color of just the space. I don't think that will work with your PromptForChoice though.

Comment: @EBGreen Changing the background color of just the space in the console sounds good. If you know how to apply that on my particular problem, please post it as an answer because it looks like it will solve my problem. Thank you for your time

Comment: Yeah, but as I said, it won't work with PromptForChoice if you intend to continue using that metho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic code sample for the method described in the comments using Read-Host for user input and changing the background color with write-host would look like this:

```
$str= "test abc1 abc2 test3"

$index = $str.IndexOf(" ")
while ($index -gt -1) {
  write-host $str.Substring(0,$index) -NoNewline
  write-host "_" -foreground "magenta" -NoNewline
  $str = $str.Substring( $index + 1, $str.length -  $index - 1);
  $index = $str.IndexOf(" ")
}
write-host $str.Substring( $index + 1, $str.length -  $index - 1);
$confirmation = Read-Host "Do you want to keep the blank on this line?"
if ($confirmation -eq 'y') {
  #do action
}
```

Edit: Included code for multiple white spaces

Code for initial Post:

```
$n = @()

$f = Get-Content C:\MyPath\*.csv 
foreach($item in $f) {

if($item -like "* *"){ 
    #$res = $host.ui.PromptForChoice("Title", "want to keep the blank on this line? `n $item", [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes, $no), 0)

    $str = $item
    $index = $str.IndexOf(" ")
    while ($index -gt -1) {
      write-host $str.Substring(0,$index) -NoNewline
      write-host "_" -foreground "magenta" -NoNewline
      $str = $str.Substring( $index + 1, $str.length -  $index - 1);
      $index = $str.IndexOf(" ")
    }
    write-host $str.Substring( $index + 1, $str.length -  $index - 1);
    $confirmation = Read-Host "Do you want to keep the blank on this line?"
    if (($confirmation -eq 'y') -or ($confirmation -eq 'Y')) {
      $n+=$item
    }
    else {
      $n+=$item -replace ' '
    }
} else {
    $n+=$item -replace ' '
}

}

$n | Set-Content  C:\MyPath\*.csv
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. Just started out with powershell. How exactly could I adapt this to my existing code? Just paste my code in the #do action part?

Comment: @CM2K I added it to your existing code. If you type anything else than 'Y' or 'y' it will replace the blanks